# Auth succeeded No requires line available

Tags: apache2, mysql

Upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 (and Apache2 2.4) server I can't use MySQL as htaccess;

Before upgrading I was using MySQL as htaccess in the virtual host - worked nicely:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/tilmelding/login>
           AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
            AuthUserFile /dev/null

            # begin auth_mysql configuration
            AuthMySQL On
            AuthMySQL_Host localhost
            AuthMySQL_User **********
            AuthMySQL_Password *********
            AuthMySQL_DB **********
            AuthMySQL_Password_Table user_info
            AuthMySQL_Username_Field user_name
            AuthMySQL_Password_Field user_passwd
            AuthMySQL_Empty_Passwords Off
            AuthMySQL_Encryption_Types PHP_MD5
            AuthMySQL_Authoritative 
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "auth_mysql test"
            Require valid-user
```

After upgrade it didn’t work.

In the logfile I got:

---

```
[:debug] [pid 31333] mod_auth_mysql.c(1578): Constructing password collection query with passfield=[user_passwd], table=[user_info], userfield=[helgoland], where_clause=[]
[:debug] [pid 31333] mod_auth_mysql.c(1410): sec->dbh in /var/www/html/tilmelding/login/ is 
[:debug] [pid 31333] mod_auth_mysql.c(1417): Ordinary query
[:debug] [pid 31333] mod_auth_mysql.c(1434): Running query: [SELECT user_passwd FROM user_info WHERE user_name='helgoland']
[:debug] [pid 31333] mod_auth_mysql.c(1522): Checking with PHP_MD5
[:debug] [pid 31333] mod_auth_mysql.c(1524): Auth succeeded
[:error] [pid 31333] No requires line available
```

I am able to do the query from CLI and get an MD5 back.

What have I missed ?

Comment: The main problem with mod_auth_dbd is that it is not working with installed php-mysql module while I am writing due to some kind of bug. The Solution mod-auth-mysql for now might be located here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905596/apache2-and-mysql-authorization/25392687#25392687)

Answer (score 2):

Just add `AuthMySQL_Authoritative Off` to .htaccess

Comment: Could you provide an explanation?

Comment: @muru no I just faced with this problem and this trick worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I've stumbled upon the exact same problem, so I came across this post.

For anyone who ends up here, this is my conclusion.

After further searching the net, most people seem to conclude that lib-apache2-mod-auth-mysql is incompatible with Apache 2.4 (standard in Ubuntu 14.04)
Moreover support for this module has stopped.

Some suggest recompiling (version 3.0.0) with some patches fixes the problem. But this seems quite "hacky".

The official "Apache" way to use basic authentication/authorization using MySQL is to use the dbd module (mod_authn_dbd). How to do this is explained quite clearly in the official Apache documentation. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authn_dbd.html.
This documentation is licensed under the Apache License.  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

So be aware that although you could install lib-apache2-mod-auth-mysql with apt-get in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS this is probably best avoided since it is inherently broken for this version.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! This seems more commentary than answer. Please edit your answer to provide simply that (perhaps the relevant portion of the docs you linked to that fixed it for you and use the link to cite the source. as well as http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 as required. This is more effective. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*AuthMySQL_Authoritative Off* also worked for me (as a line in the Virtualhost config). I believe it allows mod_auth_mysql to pass the credentials on to mod_auth for authentication.